# ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException specific scenario on database update

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While trying to insert into database, Iam getting below Stack Trace -

StackTrace":"org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0

This happens in our application login function whenever invalid login attempts are incremented. Code below in Java:

```
    User user = userRepository.getUser(userId) //@Entity object connected to USER table
    UserAuthentication userAuth = user.getUserAuthentication(); //@Entity object USER_AUTHENTICATION table

   UserAuthenticationRepository userAuthenticationRepository = //extends CrudRepository
    
    if (userAuth.getPasswordRetryCount() >= maxPasswordRetries) {
        int passwordRetry = userAuth.getPasswordRetryCount();
        passwordRetry++;
        userAuth.setPasswordRetry(passwordRetry);
        userAuth.preUpdate();
        userAuthenticationRepository.save(userAuth);
        throw new UserLockedOutException("Max attempts reached");
    } else if (isPasswordValid()) {    
        userAuth.setPasswordRetryCount(0);
        userAuth.preUpdate();
        userAuthenticationRepository.save(userAuth);
    } else {
        int passwordRetry = userAuth.getPasswordRetryCount();
        passwordRetry++;
        userAuth.setPasswordRetryCount(passwordRetry);
        userAuth.preUpdate();
        userAuthenticationRepository.save(userAuth);
        throw new InvalidPasswordException("Password is invalid");
    }
```

My understanding on ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException is this:

Let's say that thread A found Foo entity by id = 1, and before thread A have gotten to reposiroty.delete(foo);, thread B also acquired Foo entity with id = 1.

So after Foo with id = 1 is deleted by thread A, thread B will try to do the same thing, but since Foo with id = 1 is already will be deleted at that time, thread B will throw ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.

Hence, thread B was hoping to delete the acquired entity, but this entity was already deleted by the time thread B actually started to perform the deletion.

but in this case, there is NO RECORD deletion, only update of the retry count. There is also no retrieval of user record based on retry count. So...I'm confused what really causes ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. Can anyone help?